# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: database "clinilead_e " does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql-9.5

After changing the db from sqlite to postgresql(python manage.py makemigrations)running, I am getting this error.How could i overcome this?

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'clinilead_e ',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you created this database `clinilead_e` in postgres?

Comment: using psql command

Comment: Yes, have you done that?

Comment: yes i did it..after when i running i am getting this error.I change my sqlite db to postgresql db in django

Answer (score 1):

In postgres, unlike sqlite you have to create the database.

```
$ createdb clinilead_e
```

Comment: what do you get when typing `$ psql -l`?

Comment: Iam not getting anything

Comment: What OS are you on and how did you install postgres?

Comment: windows, from the postgresql website

Comment: Do you want me to unistall and install the postgresql?

Comment: Don't know if it would help. I just noticed there's a space after the "e" in `'NAME': 'clinilead_e ',`, first you can try removing that, otherwise try to log into psql and check the databases, maybe your user does not have the permissions to create or something like that.

Comment: also for commands like `createdb clinilead_e` to work, you must add the psql folders to the windows path.